# Ruby Telnet - Net::ReadTimeout: timed out while waiting for more data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sockets, printing, telnet

I am trying to connect to printer using ruby `telnet` library. I can successfully connect to printer using `telnet` library but whenever I send the command using `cmd` keyword library returns the exception:

> Net::ReadTimeout: timed out while waiting for more data

I am using below commands to connect to printer

```
localhost = Net::Telnet::new("Host" => "192.168.25.168","Port" => 20000, "Timeout" => 10)
status = ""
localhost.cmd("SELECTGROUP 1") {|c| status =  c } 

if status == "ok"
   puts "success"
else
   puts "failure"
end
```

The above `localhost.cmd` command returns string "ok" which I am expecting, or the above exception.

I want to know how to prevent `cmd` command from sending a timeout exception.

Answer (score 0):

Raising an `Exception` is the standard behaviour for when a command "fails" - such as by reaching a timeout limit. What you are really looking to do, I believe, is *gracefully handle* the exception. You can do this by use of a `rescue`:

```
localhost = Net::Telnet::new("Host" => "192.168.25.168","Port" => 20000, "Timeout" => 10)
status = ""
begin
  localhost.cmd("SELECTGROUP 1") {|c| status =  c }
rescue Net::ReadTimeout
  status = 'timeout'
end

if status == "ok"
   puts "success"
else
   puts "failure"
end
```

Note that [`Net::Telnet#cmd`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.4/libdoc/net/telnet/rdoc/Net/Telnet.html#method-i-cmd) returns the received data as a string, so your above code could in fact be simplified to something like:

```
localhost = Net::Telnet::new("Host" => "192.168.25.168","Port" => 20000, "Timeout" => 10)
begin
  if localhost.cmd("SELECTGROUP 1") == 'ok'
    puts 'success'
  else
    puts 'failure'
  end
rescue Net::ReadTimeout
  puts 'timeout'
end
```

Comment: Yes  this will work but I don't want to wait for 10 seconds timeout. I want to exist from the command as soon as it returns the data "ok"

Comment: You won't need to. It will only take 10 seconds if the command **hangs**. If `"ok"` (or anything else!) is returned sooner than that, then `localhost.cmd` returns the value immediately.

Comment: no it is not returning immediately. it returning value "Ok" then wait for 10 seconds.

Comment: Hmmm... perhaps the connection is not being closed by `"192.168.25.168:20000"`? What happens when you try this directly on the command line (i.e. not using Ruby at all)?

Answer (score 0):

The key is that you tell Net::Telnet what the prompt (of your telnet protocol) looks like. This is done by passing a Regexp to the option "Prompt". Unless Net::Telnet sees a sequence of characters that matches the prompt it will wait for more content, eventually hitting the timeout.